# How to give label my csv plot on my maps with python

Tags: python, plot, gis

```
#DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('/PlotVes.csv')

geodata = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)
geodata.plot()
     
litho_shp = gpd.read_file(r'/Litologi_Akuifer.shp')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15))

litho_shp.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='Grey', edgecolor='k',alpha=1,linewidth=1,cmap="cividis")

geodata.plot(ax=ax, color='red', markersize=10);
```

I want to show my csv's label in column "Name" on my csv plot
[CSV data read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BQsx.png)

Here is the image
[Image my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81uP.png)